# Spring data jpa @OneToMany bidirectional on same table

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to create a simple mapping for a single table relation like an orgChart.
I'm using Spring Boot with Spring data and JPA.
This is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orgchart")
public class OrgChart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private OrgChart parent;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<OrgChart> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and the test code to add some data:

```
OrgChart orgChart = new OrgChart();

OrgChart orgChart1 = new OrgChart();
orgChartRepository.save(orgChart1);

OrgChart orgChart2 = new OrgChart();
orgChartRepository.save(orgChart2);

orgChart.getChildren().add(orgChart1);
orgChart.getChildren().add(orgChart2);
OrgChart saved = orgChartRepository.save(orgChart);
```

so the table is created properly and the structure looks also ok to me:

```
id |parent_id|
---+---------+
361|         |
359|      361|
360|      361|
```

but the problem is that I don't see the parent field in the object when I fetch it from the DB:

```
List<OrgChart> children = orgChartRepository.getById(saved.getId()).getChildren()
```

here `children.get(0).getParent()` is always null. What am I doing wrong? I've already tried so many ways, is this thing possible to achieve?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following should accomplish it:

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<OrgChart> children = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private OrgChart parent;
    
    OrgChart parent = new OrgChart();
    OrgChart newOrgChart = new OrgChart();
    newOrgChart.setParent(parent);
    parent.getChildren().add(newOrgChart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")` to tell JPA that these fields are the two ends of a bidirectional relationship, not two different unidirectional ones.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: This may be because when saving a bidirectional relationship, you have to set the *owning* side. In this case the owning side is the `parent` field, so please try `orgChart1.setParent(orgChart)` before saving the `orgChart1`.

Comment: if I set the parent then when I fetch the data I see only the parent and not the children anymore. If I set both I get a stackoverflow error.